# mHandler isn't set from within a synchronized block in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, synchronization

Looking through the Android SDK framework source code, I've come across this:

```
private final class GpsLocationProviderThread extends Thread {

        public GpsLocationProviderThread() {
            super("GpsLocationProvider");
        }

        public void run() {
            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            initialize();
            Looper.prepare();
            mHandler = new ProviderHandler();
            // signal when we are initialized and ready to go
            mInitializedLatch.countDown();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }
```

(this is from Froyo's frameworks/base/location/java/com/android/internal/location/GpsLocationProvider.java)

`GpsLocationProviderThread` is an inner class of `GpsLocationProvider`, and `mHandler` is a member instance variable of `GpsLocationProvider`. This variable is set from within this thread's `run()` method, but no synchronization is applied, and `mHandler` is not `volatile`.

Why does this work? And even if 99% of the time this does work, it's not always guaranteed to work, and it's certainly not good practice. Am I correct in this understanding, or is there something subtle to this code that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Does any other thread access mHandler? We need more context.

Comment: Yes, mHandler is accessed from the outside thread, which is the main, or UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread is created when the provider is created (in its constructor), and the `mInitializedLatch` makes sure that the constructor only proceeds once the thread is up and running.

After that point, mHandler is created and valid, and since the Handler class' methods are reentrant, this system should be thread-safe. Handler, after all, is a class that is designed for inter-thread communication.

Comment: This is an old question, but I've come here having coincidentally performed a search regarding the use of `synchronized` blocks around `mHandler` in the `GpsLocationProvider` file that skyler was looking at. I think I understand why skyler asks the question: because in other parts of the code, `mHandler` is wrapped with `synchronized`, but not in the block of code shown in the question. My conclusion is that the quoted bit of code doesn't need the synchronization for the reason that @EboMike explains, but the other references to `mHandler` are synchronized because they are in public methods.

Comment: ...and, the reason for those public methods needing to synchronize calls to `mHandler` while using `mHandler` as the lock is, as far as I can tell, to prevent concurrent calls to those public methods. To do so would otherwise be a bad thing, because at least one of those public methods makes several calls to `mHandler`, which must be done as an atomic operation without other calls to `mHandler` in the meantime. That's my belief, anyhow - but would welcome further comment.